# Is there anyway to play the "sent mail" sound clip that the mail client uses?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was wondering if there was a way you could play the "sent mail" sound clip in your app without using MFMailComposeViewController. I have a custom view controller for sending messages in my app. is there a way to play the sound when the user sends the message?

Answer (score 0):

There is no function or method for that, but what you can do is find that sound in the Frameworks and play it as other sound you would have.
For example here you can find the path of the keyboard click sound:

[Increase keyboard click sound back to normal?](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-840071.html)

You will have to look for the mail sound probably in the same UIKit.Framework or the frameworks that looks like the one who has the mail stuff.